# importing wordpress site #1062 - Duplicate entry '7' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to import a Wordpress site from a live server to a mamp local server. but everytime I get the same error in the comment meta table. the error I get is #1062 - Duplicate entry '7' for key 'PRIMARY' this is the table.

--

### -- Gegevens worden geëxporteerd voor tabel `wp2_commentmeta`

INSERT INTO `wp2_commentmeta` (`meta_id`, `comment_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES
(7, 6, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(10, 9, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(11, 10, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(12, 11, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(13, 14, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(14, 15, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(15, 16, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(16, 17, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(17, 13, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(18, 12, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(19, 18, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(20, 19, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(21, 20, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(22, 21, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(23, 22, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(24, 23, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(25, 24, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(27, 26, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(28, 27, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(29, 28, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(30, 29, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(31, 30, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(32, 31, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(33, 32, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(34, 33, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(35, 34, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(36, 35, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(37, 36, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(38, 37, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(39, 38, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(40, 39, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(41, 40, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(42, 41, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(43, 42, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(44, 43, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(45, 44, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(46, 45, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(47, 46, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(48, 47, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(49, 48, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(50, 49, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(51, 50, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(52, 51, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(53, 52, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(54, 53, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(55, 54, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(56, 55, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(57, 56, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(58, 57, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(59, 58, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(60, 59, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(61, 60, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(62, 61, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(63, 62, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(64, 63, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(65, 64, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(66, 65, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(67, 66, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(68, 67, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(69, 68, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(70, 69, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(71, 70, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(72, 71, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(76, 75, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(80, 79, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(81, 80, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(82, 81, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(83, 82, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(85, 84, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(86, 85, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(87, 86, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(88, 87, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(89, 88, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(90, 89, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(91, 90, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(92, 91, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(93, 92, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(95, 94, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(96, 95, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(97, 96, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(98, 97, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(99, 98, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(100, 99, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(101, 100, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(102, 101, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(103, 102, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(104, 103, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(105, 104, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(106, 105, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(107, 106, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(108, 107, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(109, 108, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(110, 109, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(111, 110, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(112, 111, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(113, 112, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(114, 113, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(115, 114, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(116, 115, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(117, 116, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(118, 117, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(119, 118, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(120, 119, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(121, 120, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(122, 121, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(123, 122, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(124, 123, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(125, 124, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(126, 125, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(127, 127, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(129, 129, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(131, 131, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(133, 133, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(135, 135, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(137, 137, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(139, 139, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(141, 141, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(143, 143, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(145, 145, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(147, 147, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(149, 149, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(151, 151, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(153, 153, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(155, 155, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(157, 157, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(159, 159, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(161, 161, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(163, 163, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(165, 165, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(167, 167, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(169, 169, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(171, 171, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(173, 173, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(175, 175, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(177, 177, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(179, 179, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(181, 181, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(183, 183, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(185, 185, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(187, 187, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(189, 189, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(191, 191, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(193, 193, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(195, 195, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(197, 197, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(199, 199, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(201, 201, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(203, 203, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(205, 205, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(207, 207, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(209, 209, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(211, 211, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(213, 213, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(215, 215, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(217, 217, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(219, 219, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(221, 221, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(223, 223, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(225, 225, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(227, 227, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(229, 229, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(231, 231, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(233, 233, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(235, 235, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(237, 237, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(239, 239, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(241, 241, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(243, 243, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(245, 245, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(247, 247, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(249, 249, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(251, 251, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(253, 253, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(255, 255, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(257, 259, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(259, 261, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(261, 263, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(263, 265, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(265, 257, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(267, 267, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(269, 269, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(271, 271, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(273, 273, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(275, 275, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(277, 277, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(279, 279, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(281, 281, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(283, 283, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(285, 285, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(287, 287, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(289, 289, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(291, 291, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(293, 293, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(295, 295, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(297, 297, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(299, 299, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(301, 301, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(303, 303, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(305, 305, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(307, 307, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(309, 309, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(311, 311, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(313, 313, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(315, 315, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(317, 317, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(319, 319, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(321, 323, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(323, 325, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(325, 327, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(327, 329, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(329, 321, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(331, 333, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(333, 335, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(335, 337, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(337, 339, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(339, 331, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(341, 341, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(343, 343, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(345, 345, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(347, 347, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(349, 349, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(351, 351, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(353, 353, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(355, 355, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(357, 357, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(359, 359, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(361, 363, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(363, 365, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(365, 367, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(367, 369, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(369, 361, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(371, 371, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(373, 373, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(375, 375, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(377, 377, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(379, 379, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(381, 383, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(383, 385, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(385, 387, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(387, 389, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(389, 391, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(391, 393, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(393, 395, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(395, 397, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(397, 401, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(399, 403, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(401, 425, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(403, 427, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(405, 423, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(407, 421, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(409, 419, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(411, 417, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(413, 415, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(415, 413, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(417, 411, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(419, 409, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(421, 407, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(423, 405, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(425, 399, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(427, 381, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(429, 439, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(431, 441, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(433, 443, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(435, 445, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(437, 447, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(439, 449, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(441, 451, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(443, 453, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(445, 465, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(447, 467, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(449, 469, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(451, 471, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(453, 475, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(455, 477, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(457, 505, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(459, 507, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(461, 503, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(463, 501, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(465, 499, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(467, 497, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(469, 495, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(471, 493, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(473, 491, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(475, 489, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(477, 487, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(479, 485, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(481, 483, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(483, 481, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(485, 479, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(487, 473, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(489, 463, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(491, 461, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(493, 459, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(495, 457, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(497, 455, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(499, 437, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(501, 435, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(503, 433, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(505, 431, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(507, 429, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'),
(509, 509, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(511, 511, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(513, 513, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(515, 515, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(517, 517, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(519, 519, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(521, 521, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(523, 523, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(525, 525, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(527, 527, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(529, 529, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(531, 531, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(533, 533, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(535, 535, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(537, 537, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(539, 539, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(541, 541, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(543, 543, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(545, 545, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(547, 547, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(549, 549, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(551, 551, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(553, 553, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(555, 555, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(557, 557, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(559, 559, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(561, 561, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(563, 563, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(565, 565, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(567, 567, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(569, 569, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(571, 571, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(573, 573, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(575, 575, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(577, 577, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(579, 579, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(581, 581, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(583, 583, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(585, 587, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(587, 589, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(589, 591, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(591, 593, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(593, 595, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(595, 597, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(597, 599, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(599, 607, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(601, 613, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(603, 615, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(605, 617, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(607, 619, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(609, 621, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(611, 623, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(613, 625, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(615, 627, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(617, 629, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(619, 631, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(621, 633, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(623, 635, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(625, 641, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(627, 643, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(629, 645, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(631, 647, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(633, 649, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(635, 651, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(637, 653, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(639, 655, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(641, 657, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(643, 659, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(645, 661, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(647, 663, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(649, 665, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(651, 667, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(653, 669, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(655, 671, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(657, 673, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(659, 675, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(661, 677, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(663, 683, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(665, 685, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(667, 687, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(669, 689, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(671, 691, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(673, 693, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(675, 695, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(677, 697, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(679, 699, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(681, 701, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(683, 703, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(685, 705, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(687, 707, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(689, 709, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(691, 711, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(693, 713, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(695, 715, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(697, 717, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(699, 719, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(701, 721, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(703, 723, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(705, 725, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(707, 727, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(709, 729, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(711, 731, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(713, 733, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(715, 735, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(717, 737, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(719, 739, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(721, 741, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(723, 743, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(725, 745, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(727, 747, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(729, 749, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(731, 751, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(733, 753, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(735, 755, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(737, 757, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(739, 759, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(741, 761, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(743, 763, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(751, 771, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(753, 773, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(755, 775, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(757, 777, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(759, 779, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(761, 781, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(763, 783, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(765, 785, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(767, 787, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(769, 789, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(771, 791, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(773, 793, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(775, 795, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(777, 797, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(779, 799, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(781, 801, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(783, 803, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(785, 805, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(787, 807, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(789, 809, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(791, 811, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(793, 813, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(795, 815, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(797, 817, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(799, 819, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(801, 821, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(803, 823, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(805, 825, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(807, 827, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(809, 829, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(811, 831, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(813, 833, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(815, 835, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(817, 837, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(819, 839, 'is_customer_note', '0'),
(821, 841, 'is_customer_note', '0');

I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: There are no issues with the data you are trying to load. Perhaps you have some data present before you attempt the insert or maybe the error is comiing from a trigger. NB table definition can be found https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_commentmeta

Comment: do you have any idea what the trigger could be cause I am clueless what to do?

Comment: I don't know wp  so no but this may help - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-triggers.html

Answer (score 0):

I already had a similar error. Rebuilding the structure of my tables had corrected this error

```
ALTER TABLE `wp2_commentmeta`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
  ADD KEY `comment_id` (`comment_id`),
  ADD KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(1));

ALTER TABLE `wp2_commentmeta`
  MODIFY `meta_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: thank you for answering my question. I am kind of a noob in sql so do I just need to add this in my sql file or how do is solve this problem?